# Add an EXE file to a project, so that it will be copied to the Bin/Debug folder just like a DLL?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, tfs

I need my C# project to launch another EXE program during execution. This executable needs to be placed in the same folder as the C# program is placed on building the solution, for example, the debug folder -- just like DLL file references -- so that when my team members check the project out from TFS, and debug, the EXE is found when my C# code tries to call it.

However, the EXE is not a reference per se, and so it cannot be added as a reference, even though I want it to be copied around in the same manner as a reference.

Is there a reasonable solution for this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can package the EXE with your c# program when you are ready to release it with an installer, but I know that wasn't your actual question.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can go the properties of the file, and under Copy to output Directory select, `copy if newer`

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You could add the executable as item to your C# project and in its properties set its `Copy to Output Directory` property to `Copy always`. This way the executable will be copied to the output folder (`bin\Debug` or `bin\Release`) everytime you compile your project.

Answer (score 2):

Create a batch file that is performing the copy action after the build. It is possible to do other stuff pre-build and post build. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks.aspx

Comment: Vote for this because if you use this exe in different solutions you can replace only one file and all solutions will use the new one.

Answer (score 1):

Package the `.exe` with the setup of your program.

Just add it to the `Applications Folder`. Its the same as it being in the `bin/Debug` folder.